# About transistor datasheets

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I am looking at the datasheet of the PMOS enhancement transistor MTP2955V from Motorola. I was wondering why they write VDS instead of VSD and VGS as if it where posivite in this graph. Is not the Source terminal at a higher potential than the Drain terminal and VGS<0 for a PMOS that is operating ?

[image]

Comment: The order of the letter in the term VDS, or any other acronym or phrase,  does not usually imply any polarity.

Comment: Just to add here, it can, and often does, just maybe not half or most of the time